# VBS "PasteSpecial"

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am trying to copy/paste some values from a source XLS to a target XLS. The cells in the target have custom formats, which I need to keep.

I ended up using:

```
target.Worksheets("Sheet 2").PasteSpecial -4163 -4142, True, False
```

This does the job of keeping the format, but it doesn't paste the actual value into the target cell, but rather a reference to the source XLS. Can anyone help me and explain, how I can actually paste the value (**but** still keep the target's format)?

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you're confusing the [`Worksheet.PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-pastespecial-method-excel) method with the [`Range.PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel) method.

Try this:

```
target.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial -4104, -4142, True, False
```